# jQuery onclick function won't fire on nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a web-page that features two buttons at the top which are meant to sort some data later in the page.  For some reason I can't get the nested `#byFilter` to accept an `onclick(function())`

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.filter').click(function() {
                console.log('I\'ve gotten');

            });

            $('#byName').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                console.log('this far');

            });

            //just some stuff with geolocation
            getLocation().done(function() {

                getStuff(origin);

            });
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="Sortby">

            <div class="filter" id="#byName">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="filter" id="#byDistance">
                Distance
            </div>
            <br style="clear:both;">
```

So when I load the page and click on the divs, all I get is "I've gotten"

I don't remember any extra step required to attach a click listener to a nested div like this, but I can't seem to get this to work.  I fear I'm missing something quite trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the pound`(#)` signs in the i`d` attributes themselves. Pound is only used in a *selector* as a short-hand to refer to an id attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.filter').click(function() {
    console.log('I\'ve gotten');

  });

  $('#byName').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('this far');

  });

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter" id="byName">
  Name
</div>
<div class="filter" id="byDistance">
  Distance
</div>
<br style="clear:both;">
```

Comment: There it is.  I think it's time I took a break haha.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel bad I just spent 10 mins trying to figure it out too and came back and this guy beat me too it :)

Comment: I spoke too soon :/ even doing something as simple as getting their .text() doesn't work.  It seems jQuery just can't access these divs.

Comment: @Csteele5, reproduce the problema and what youre trying to do in a http://jsfiddle.net